# Can not find a specific regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to scrap specific information from the site but I am receiving an error. Here is the simplified version of the main problem:

```
import re

b='href="/bp/vendor?vendorCodes=C901U">C901U</a></span></div></div></div><div heyaa'

c=re.search('href="/bp/vendor?vendorCodes=C901U">C901U</a></span></div></div></div><div',b)
```

If I try to find what is in c I receive this error:

```
c.group()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#87>", line 1, in <module>
    c.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `?` is a special character in regex. Escape it: `\?`.

Comment: In general, don't use regular expressions to parse HTML at all; use an HTML parser.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and start with your own research. I'm voting to close this question because the solution is trivial: either you forgot `?` is special or you weren't aware because you aren't familiar enough with regex. If it's the latter, you could maybe check out the official Python [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Regex Matching Error](/q/1268761/90527)", "[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](/a/1732454/90527)", "[regex add questionmark as a character \[duplicate\]](/q/31951614/90527)"